# How can I change the fallback font on Android in Japanese?

Tags: sony-xperia, fonts

I have a Sony Xperia 10 V that was sold in Japan, and is set to use Japanese as the primary UI language. In a few places, text in the Latin alphabet looks awful. Here's an example from the Amazon app, where the input at the top is fine but the results are bad:

> [image]

This also happens in the Wikipedia app, but not in English articles - only to English text in Japanese articles. I believe it happens in other places as well, but I don't remember them all.

I believe that either this is because the default Japanese font has awful Latin alphabet glyphs that are being used, or a bad fallback is configured for those glyphs. How can I diagnose what is happening and fix it?